# There is no info about reviewing 20 triage questions

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

There is no info about reviewing 20 triage questions then get a "Thanks" popup block:

http://screencast.com/t/w7z8BcEK2

I think it will be better to add some text like this above "thanks" block

http://screencast.com/t/KXST3ggx49K

Comment: This happens in any circumstance where the review queue is unable to serve you another item (when you reach your limit *or* if the queue is empty).